# Что делать, если после форматирования текста появляются двойные кавычки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть код:

```
async def delpartner(ctx, time: typing.Optional[int]):
     with open("config.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
          data = json.load(jsonFile)
          names = data.get('partners')
          for idx, id in enumerate(names):
               if id['id'] == time:
                    del names[idx]
                    names1 = ' '.join(map(str, names))
                    names2 = names1.replace('"', ' ')
                    break
                    jsonFile.close()
```

Суть проблемы: при обработки вывода строкой `names1 = ' '.join(map(str, names))` в выводе появляются двойные кавычки.

В JSON файле строка появляется следующим образом:

```
{
  "partners": [
    "{'id': 1, 'channel_name': 'test'}"
  ]
}
```

Что должно получится на деле:

```
{
    "partners": [

            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test"
            }
    ]
}
```

Вопрос: как записать вывод в JSON без этих кавычек?

Правка:

Раньше в JSON записывались данные, и они выглядели так:

```
{
  "partners": [
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Мне не нужно было добавление лишних квадратных скобок, я вписал строки:

```
                    names1 = ' '.join(map(str, names))
                    names2 = names1.replace('"', ' ')
```

Теперь вместо квадратных скобок стоят двойные кавычки...
Как можно убрать скобки или кавычки?

Comment: Приведите пример данных из json файла, на которых можно увидеть описываемую вами проблему.

Comment: Вот JSON с примером полностью:
```{
  "users": [
    "{'id': 1, 'channel_name': 'test'}"
  ]
}```

Comment: Нет, исходный файл, который вы открываете. И что вы хотите получить. Добавьте примеры в сам вопрос. Очевидно, это не исходный JSON, т.к. в нем нет ключа `'partners'`

Comment: Ввёл правки в вопрос, возможно, станет понятнее.

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "появляется", откуда она там появляется? `"{'id': 1, 'channel_name': 'test'}"` - это питоновский словарь сконвертированный в строку через str и записанный в json. Тут нужно исправлять тот код, который этот json создает.

Comment: Хорошо, давайте вернёмся на пару моих действий назад:

Был код без строк

```names1 = ' '.join(map(str, names))
names2 = names1.replace('"', ' ')```

Но в выводе вместо двойных кавычек были квадратные скобки, мне надо было их убрать, я добавил 2 строки, приведённые выше.
Теперь там стоят двойные кавычки...

Comment: Где были лишние квадратные скобки? Добавьте в вопрос пример как это выглядело, от чего вы собственно пытались избавиться. Через преобразование в строку вы от кавычек не избавитесь, строка всегда в кавычках в `json` хранится.

Comment: Добавил информацию.

Comment: `data['partners'] = data['partners'][0]` и всё, мне кажется, больше ничего не нужно.

Comment: Не очень сильно помогло. Точнее вообще не помогло.

Comment: В смысле ничего не поменялось? Остальной код не нужен тогда вообще, просто поменять так и записать

Comment: Работает! Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько в итоге удалось разобраться в комментариях, по ключу `partners` лежал список списков (а внутри дальше был словарь) и нужно было уменьшить вложенность, просто взяв из списка списков первый список:

```py
data['partners'] = data['partners'][0]
```

А преобразование в строку как в коде вопроса не позволяло решить проблему, потому что строка в `json` помещается в кавычках и от этих
кавычек избавиться никак нельзя.

Но это решение будет правильно работать только в случае, когда `parnters` всегда содержит ровно один элемент. В других случаях нужно будет делать по-другому.